# How to create a simple settings menu in android? (with xmls & activities files)

Tags: java, android, settings, preference

I want to create a settings menu in my android app.
I tried different ways to create a simple settings menu, but all of them had a lot of errors or were not working properly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new project. To show you how this could be done paste this into your main launcher activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings" >
        <EditTextPreference
                android:title="Password"
                android:summary="Set Your Password"
                android:key="prefUserPassword"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Security Settings" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefLockScreen"
            android:summary="Lock The Screen With Password"
            android:title="Screen Lock" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>

        <ListPreference
            android:key="prefUpdateFrequency"
            android:title="Reminder for Updation"
            android:summary="Set Update Reminder Frequency"
            android:entries="@array/updateFrequency"
            android:entryValues="@array/updateFrequencyValues"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Since we have used arrays here, We need to define it inside array.xml file.
Create an arrays.xml file  inside values folder and write following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="updateFrequency">
        <item name="1">Daily</item>
        <item name="7">Weekly</item>
        <item name="3">Yearly</item>
        <item name="0">Never(I will Myself) </item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="updateFrequencyValues">
        <item name="1">1</item>
        <item name="7">7</item>
        <item name="30">30</item>
        <item name="0">0</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

This is purely a sample taken from [here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/09/preferenceactivity-in-android-example.html)

Comment: Thank you so much.
But i have this error:      Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- PreferenceCategory (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- PreferenceScreen (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Comment: I think its better you find a tutorial online and step through each one. Look for tutorials on preferenceActivity in android. There are lots.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your help